# How can I transform / cast a PHP parent object to a child object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Reason**

I got a legacy system with a table containing slugs.

When those records match, it represents some kind of page with a layout ID.

Because these pages can have different resource needs it depends on the layout ID which tables can be joined with.

I use Laravel's Eloquent models.

What I would like is to have a child model that holds the layout specific relations.

```
class Page extends Model {
    // relation 1, 2, 3 that are always present
}

class ArticlePage extends Page {
    // relation 4 and 5, that are only present on an ArticlePage
}
```

However in my controller, in order to know which layout I need, I already have to query:

url: **/{slug}**

```
$page = Slug::where('slug', $slug)->page;

if ($page->layout_id === 6) {
    //transform $page (Page) to an ArticlePage
}
```

Because of this I get an instance of Page, but I would like to transform or cast it to an instance of ArticlePage to load it's additional relations. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might want to look at polymorphic relations:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to look into [Polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) in Laravel to achieve this. A Polymorphic Relation would allow you to retrieve a different model based on the *type* of field it is. In your `Slug` model you would need something like this:

```
public function page()
{
    return $this->morphTo('page', 'layout_id', 'id');
}
```

In one of your service providers, e.g. `AppServiceProvider` you would need to provide a *Morph Map* to tell Laravel to map certain IDs to certain model classes. For example:

```
Relation::morphMap([
    1 => Page::class,
    // ...
    6 => ArticlePage::class,
]);
```

Now, whenever you use the `page` relation, Laravel will check the type and give you the correct model back.

**Note:** I'm not 100% sure on the parameters etc. and I haven't tested but you should be able to work it out from the docs.

---

If your `layout_id` is on the `Page` model, the only solution I see is to add a method to your `Page` model that is able to *convert* your existing page into an `ArticlePage`, or other page type, based on its `layout_id` property. You should be able to try something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    const LAYOUT_ARTICLE = 6;

    protected $layoutMappings = [
        // Add your other mappings here
        self::LAYOUT_ARTICLE => ArticlePage::class
    ];

    public function toLayoutPage()
    {
        $class = $this->layoutMappings[$this->layout_id];

        if (class_exists($class)) {
            return (new $class())
                ->newInstance([], true)
                ->setRawAttributes($this->getAttributes());
        }

        throw new \Exception('Invalid layout.');
    }
}
```

What this does is look for a mapping based on your `layout_id` property, and then it creates a new class of the correct type, filling its attributes with those from the page you're creating from. This should be all you need, if you take a look at Laravel's `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent::newFromBuilder()` method, which Laravel calls when it creates new model instances, you can see what's going on and how I've gotten the code above. You should be able to just use it like this:

```
$page = Slug::where('slug', $slug)
            ->first()
            ->page
            ->toLayoutPage();
```

That will give you an instance of `ArticlePage`

Comment: This is an elegant solution. That is, if you are into polymorphic relations of course :)

Comment: A little late but the only flaw with this solution (for me) is that the **layoutID** is on the Page model itself, not on Slug.

Comment: @ThomasMoors See my updated answer, hopefully that will help you if polymorphic relations aren't the way to go for you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no built in function for this.
But you could do something like this.

```
  $page = Slug::where('slug', $slug)->page;

  if ($page->layout_id === 6) {
      $page = ArticlePage::fromPage($page);
  }
```

And then on the ArticlePage create the static method

```
public static function fromPage(Page $page)
{
   $articlePage = new self();

   foreach($page->getAttributes() as $key => $attribute) {
       $articlePage->{$key} = $attribute;
   }

   return $articlePage
}
```

Depending on your use-case might be smart to create a static method that does this automatically on the relation page() for Slug.

Comment: $page->getAttributes() could be replaced by $page->toArray()
This would leverage accessors and type casting. For example if your attribute casted as json usage of getAttributes would get the value as a string, thus corrupting data type.