# Can I dynamically assign the Class of a Laravel Eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

This question comes forth from [How can I transform / cast a PHP parent object to a child object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098167/how-can-i-transform-cast-a-php-parent-object-to-a-child-object)

Currently I have this code:

```
class Page extends Model {
    // relation 1, 2, 3 that are always present
}

class ArticlePage extends Page {
    // relation 4 and 5, that are only present on an ArticlePage
}

class PageSlug extends Model {

    public function page()
    {
        $page = Page::find($this->hd_pag_ID)
        ->first();

        if (!$page instanceof Page) {
            return null;
        }

       switch ($page->layout_id) {
           case PageLayout::ARTICLE:
               return $this->hasOne(ArticlePage::class, 'category_id', 'hd_pag_ID');
           default:
               return $this->hasOne(Page::class, 'category_id', 'hd_pag_ID');
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see I now query Page first, which is undesirable. Can I change the Class that is used without querying Page seperately?

[image]

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations is probably what you want to be looking at.

Comment: @Tuim Can you please answer with how I can use it my situation? Because the problem with this approach is that the property layout_id is on the Page tabel and not on the PageSlug

Comment: Can you provide us your database scheme?

Comment: @MakashovNurbol yes, although the models describe them as well.

Comment: Ok, I have given it some thought. You cannot get around this with just a polymorphic relation. I think it would be best to move PageSlug inside your Page class (I have no domain knowledge or what the PageSlug class does for you) but going by the class name I figured it could be a property of Page.

Comment: @Tuim thanks for thinking along, but I cannot change the tables too much as it's part of a very big application. page_slug is a lookup table for slugs (like domain.nl/dogs the slug is dogs). And page is a table containing info about what layout to use and which data to load.